# Why NLTK uses regular expressions for word tokenization, but training for sentence tokenization?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I am using NLTK in python. I understood that it uses regular expressions in its word tokenization functions, such as TreebankWordTokenizer.tokenize(), but it uses trained models (pickle files) for sentence tokenization. I don't understand why they don't use training for word tokenization? Does it imply that sentence tokenization is a harder task?

Comment: Because words are easily described with regular expressions?

Comment: Cos regex is fun =) And Elephant is one of the few stable version of smart tokenization see https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/1214

Comment: Question, if you're going to train the model for tokenization, what is your training gold data? If it's going to be the output for a regex tokenizer and not manually checked or tokenized, then it's just using the wheels for the sake of using the wheels although you don't want to move anything =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can say that sentence splitting is harder than (word) tokenisation. But tokenisation depends on sentence splitting, so errors in sentence splitting will propagate to tokenisation. Therefore you'd want to have reliable sentence splitting, so that you don't have to make up for it in tokenisation. And it turns out that once you have good sentence splitting, tokenisation works pretty well with regexes.

Why is that? – One of the major ambiguities in tokenisation (in Latin script languages, at least) is the period ("."): It can be a full stop (thus a token of its own), an abbreviation mark (belonging to that abbreviation token), or something special (like part of a URL, a decimal fraction, ...). Once the sentence splitter has figured out the first case (full stops), the tokeniser can concentrate on the rest. And identifying stuff like URLs is exactly what you would use a regex for, isn't it?

The sentence splitter's main job, on the other hand, is to find abbreviations with a period. You can create a list for that by hand – or you can train it on a big text collection. The good thing is, it's *unsupervised* training – you just feed in the plain text, and the splitter collects abbreviations. The intuition is: If a token almost always appears with a period, then it's probably an abbreviation.